# cocos2dx - Turn off Predictive text on TextFieldTTF

Tags: ios, textfield, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using cocos2dx extension `TextFieldTTF` for inputs. The problem with it is I can't turn off `Predictive Text`, even if it is turned off from device settings.

Problem become worse for Passwords, as it shows the password as the Predictive Text to the user.

Can anyone help me to overcome this problem?

**See the screen below for more clarification**

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well in case of passwords you can use

```
textfield->setSecureTextEntry(1);
```

It will not take predictive text

Comment: Well it doesn't turn off Predictive Text in any case.. I am already doing this, see my question..

Comment: ok..now look at the editbox class.. may be that can help http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/EditBox

Comment: Yes, EditBox does work well, but it has another problem that I can't design my interface as required, the textfield starts from left alignment, you can't change it.

Comment: @iphonic yes,  it seems they have alignment issues in EditBox.

Comment: seems like a bug then, try retracting "setSecureTextEntry" function and see if you correct that bug.